# .remove jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I have this simple jquery code, if I have more than 2 <.tr><./tr> tags I want to remove td.checkout class inside of second <.tr> row.

**jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var count = $(".mini-cart-total > table > tbody > tr").length;
    if (count > 2 ) {
        $(".mini-cart-total > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.checkout").remove();
    }

});
```

**my html/php structure looks like this:**

```
<div class="mini-cart-total">
  <table>
    <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="right"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?></b></td>
      <td class="right"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
      <td class="checkout"><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></td>        
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

for some reason, I can't get this working

Comment: I am not shure, if `tbody` is added by the browser DOM automatically, but you are missing it in your HTML-code, but are referring to it in your jquery-code.

Comment: .remove() is definitely working. Most likely you just haven't actually selected an element for it to remove.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/avFz4/1/

Comment: tbody is added automatically, therefore i refer to it in my jquery

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/N4vLK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".mini-cart-total .checkout").remove();`

Comment: yes, this was the correct answer, well not exactly but I got the point, w/o the ">" it works fine, thanks again